Two equivalent definitions of locally closed
We say that a subset $A\subset X$ in a topological space $X$ is locally closed if every $x\in A$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ in $X$ for which $A\cap U_x$ is closed in $U_x$.
Problem: Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$. Show that $A\subset X$ is locally closed if and only if $A$ is an intersection of an open and a closed set in $X$.
So far: The $(\Leftarrow)$ direction is very straight forward, but I'm a bit stuck on $(\Rightarrow)$. Supposing $A$ is locally closed, we want to write $A=U\cap F$, where $U$ is open in $X$ and $F$ is closed in $X$. My thinking is choosing $U=\cup_{x\in A}U_x$, which is open in $X$ since it's a union of open sets, and $F=\bar{A}$, which clearly is closed. I can show $A\subset U\cap F$, but I'm stuck on $U\cap F\subset A$, if this even holds?

In general, there is a notion of fundamental covering, namely a covering $\mathcal V$ of a topological space $X$ is fundamental if and only if the following equivalent conditions hold: 1) for all $C\subseteq X$, $C$ is closed if and only if, for all $U\in\mathcal V$, $C\cap U$ is closed in $U$; 2) for all $C\subseteq X$, $C$ is open if and only if, for all $U\in \mathcal V$, $C\cap U$ is open in $U$. Open coverings are fundamental. Then you can apply this to $\mathcal V={U\text{ open},:, F\cap U\text{ is closed in U}}$, which is an open cover of $\bigcup \mathcal V\supseteq F$.

Also this may prove helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/736302 @SassatelliGiulio I suppose the point is OP does not know why open covers are fundamental coverings (btw: I normally have heard the language of "generating the topology" rather than fundamental covering)

@FShrike Oh the humanity. I guess they'll have to prove a lemma. I don't know the English term, my general topology book is in Italian.

Thanks @FShrike, didn't find that question while searching but the answers helped.
